# Improve speed when numpy array works with sympy matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I am confused sometimes when I want to get an analytical expression in terms of certain variables. In the following case, one is a Numpy array (T) and the other is a Sympy matrix (X). I know it is not a good idea to directly multiply them, so I decide to convert T to a Sympy matrix. However, it takes ages to get the result for this large-sized matrix. Are there any more efficient ways? Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

T =  np.random.rand(100, 5000)
x = sp.symbols('x:'+str(5000))
X = sp.Matrix(x)
W = sp.Matrix(T)
V = W * X
```

Comment: why not use a numpy matrix?

Comment: We don't talk about efficiency and speed when working with `sympy` expressions.  `numpy` arrays are designed for that, with compiled code operating on a compact data storage.  I don't know if anything in `sympy` is compiled.  It's processing of Matrix is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially more efficient ways to do this. One possibility if you want a "compiled" version of SymPy is to use SymEngine which is more limited in scope than SymPy but can do what you seem to be asking for faster than SymPy (It's basically a reimplementation of certain parts of SymPy in C++):

```
import numpy as np
import symengine as sp # <<-- changed import

T =  np.random.rand(100, 5000)
x = sp.symbols('x:'+str(5000))
X = sp.Matrix(x)
W = sp.Matrix(T.tolist())  # Need tolist() here
V = W * X
```

This still takes a while but it is faster than SymPy. In any case though there is almost certainly a better way of approaching your *actual* problem than computing the illustrated matrix product. The matrix `V` here is really just an inefficient representation of the original numpy array `T`. I expect that whatever it is that you want to do with `V` could be done more directly with `T`.